# Keep Dojo Select options-pane visible on click

Tags: javascript, dojo

The default behaviour for Dijit/Form/Select option is when you click it - it would close the options pane and assign the value to Select.

I would like options-pane to stay visible even when you click any of it. So the pane would disappear only if you would click outside of it.

How can I prevent options-pane from disappearing?

Comment: you have to dig in the select code, and you have to change the base widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an advice to the closeDropDown function.

```
aspect.around(myselect, 'closeDropDown', function(closeDropDown) {
  return function(focus) {
    if (focus == false) {
      closeDropDown.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  }
})
```

See working example.

http://jsfiddle.net/RichAyotte/a85y8hnm/

Answer (score 1):

You can hook into the "change" event of Select widget then call it's openDropDown() function every time the value changes.  Its not a 100% solution but it might get you to where you want.

Here is a jsfiddle with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/kagant15/3st69xbv/

```
var myselect = new Select({
    name: "myselect",
    options: [
        { label: "TN", value: "Tennessee" },
        { label: "VA", value: "Virginia", selected: true },
        { label: "WA", value: "Washington" },
        { label: "FL", value: "Florida" },
        { label: "CA", value: "California" }
    ]
}, "myselect");

myselect.on("change", function(){
    this.openDropDown();
})
```